# Can't post in friends wall anymore with my Rails app and Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I was using this in my app to post to users friends' wall:

```
Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(facebook_token).put_wall_post("My message", {:link => "http://www.mywebsite.com.br/invitation/#{uniq_link}"}, uid)
```

And it was all working fine, i ask for publish_stream and manage_friendlists permissions, but now, if someone send an invitation to me, i receive the notification but can't see the message or the link, is something wrong with my app? With koala? Facebook changed something? The fact that i already posted in a lot of walls is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had a similar problem, but with fb_graph gem. Seems like my access_token was changed without me knowing. I guess the first place you should go is to do just that at the Facebook Developer App [site](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

Another thing I did was to just use the Facebook Social plugin instead via their Javascript API. I found that to be slightly more reliable and I don't have to rely on a gem to do it.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: yeah i tried to use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/, I want something very similar, but the thing is that i dont want to invite people to my app, i want to invite them to my website

Comment: hmm, i think i will redo my app with facebook javascript sdk then

Comment: damn, i tried by using js sdk too but my app just wont post on my friends wall, just on my own wall

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out :).